# Apache POI : Check if a column is empty

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to check if a column is empty or not in .xlsx files but couldn't find anything smoother than this :

```
    public static boolean isColumnEmpty(int column, int firstRow, XSSFSheet sheet) {


    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(firstRow);

    while (row != null) {
        Cell c = row.getCell(column, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
        if (c != null) {
            return false;
        }
        row = sheet.getRow(firstRow++);
    }
    return true;

}
```

`firstRow` is just the row you want to start with (actually my column isn't completely empty, there still is a header).

I wonder if some of you had better ideas!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217047/how-to-determine-empty-row

Comment: You probably need to check for `Blank` cells too - those tend to be ones with no value in but some formatting

Comment: @Gagravarr You are indeed right. I changed the code!

Comment: @assylias Well, I am talking about columns and not rows. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @Fitz I assumed the code would be almost the same (just swapping rows/columns)...

Comment: @assylias I am pretty sure it is not the case as nothing seems to be provided in Apache POI to get thru the columns. But I understand your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer varies on how sparse the physical rows are in your sheet, your desire to have simple code, and how much you care about execution speed.

A good compromise of the three would only loop through physical rows, and perform decently well as long as `startRow` is much closer to `getFirstRowNum()` than `getLastRowNum()`.

```
public static boolean isColumnEmpty(Sheet sheet, int columnIndex, int startRow) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        if (row.getRowNum() < startRow) continue;
        Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
        if (cell != null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For a workbook with dense rows, your code is better.

For the code that does the least work, you could combine these two approaches (I prefer `for`-loops over `while`-loops as it's quicker to verify that your code won't get stuck in an infinite loop)

```
public static boolean isColumnEmpty(Sheet sheet, int columnIndex, int startRow) {
    int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    // No need to check rows above the first row
    startRow = Math.max(startRow, firstRow);
    int numRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    // Compute an estimate of the number of rows that each method
    // will access.
    // Assume the cost to access one row is the same
    // between an explicit getRow() or through the rowIterator.
    // Assume physical rows are uniformly spaced, which is unlikely true
    // but the best estimate possible without iterating over the rows.
    double rowDensity = (lastRow - firstRow + 1) / numRows;
    double estimatedForEachLoopCost = numRows;
    double estimatedForLoopCost = (lastRow - startRow) + 1) * rowDensity;
    if (estimatedForEachLoopCost < estimatedForLoopCost) {
        // for-each iteration
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            if (row.getRowNum() < startRow) continue;
            Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if (cell != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        for (int r=startRow; r<=lastRow; r++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
            if (row == null) continue;
            Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if (cell != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you *really* care about performance, you can fork POI and write a method to expose the `TreeMap<Integer, XSSFRow>` that `XSSFSheet` uses to access the rows.
Then you could access the minimal number of rows with `_rows.tailMap(startRow, inclusive=true)`.

If you put in a patch and test case on the POI bugzilla for a method that returns `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSortedMap(_rows.subMap(startRow, true, endRow, true))` from HSSF, XSSF, and SXSSF (fails if start row or end row are outside access window, or uses a column tracker similar to autosize column tracker), then add an isColumnEmpty function to the appropriate class, then you could avoid maintaining a fork if your patch gets accepted.